# Put external td with a class name into div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 'htm' file saved as `ahblog.htm` inside this file is a `td` element with class name `content topContent topContentBox`. What I want to do is take the `td` element and place it into a `div` in the main code which is named `wrap`. below is as far as I got but doesn't work. If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
     $('#wrap').load('site/ahblog.htm .content topContent topContentBox');
 });
```

Below is some of my 'php' code.

```
<?php 
include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html=file_get_html( 'http://achievementhunter.com/blog/');
$html->save('site/ahblog.htm')                      
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="site/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function() {
$('#wrap').click(function (event)
{
event.preventDefault();
});
$('#wrap').load('site/rtnews.htm #postsArea');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use .js file inclusion?

Comment: Can you show a bit of html also?

Comment: You don't have a "td class", you have a "td element which has a class". Does the `td` (the class in particular) look something like this: `<td class="content topContent topContentBox"></td>`, or are those classes on different elements?

Comment: Have you tried $(document) without the single quotes?

Comment: sorry I was not sure what to call it but it is called `<td class="content topContent topContentBox"></td>. I will add some html code to my question to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct selector for a single item identified by the three classes would be :

```
// "." for class selectors, no space for "one item which holds all classes"
$('#wrap').load('site/ahblog.htm .content.topContent.topContentBox');
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are trying to do something like this :

```
$.get('site/ahblog.htm', function(html){
    $(html).find('.content.topContent.topContentBox').appendTo('#wrap');
});
```

Comment: If you are using a local file and chrome. You don't need the `--disable-web-security` option ?

Comment: @TCHdvlp I don't get what you mean

Comment: Some browsers doesn't allow you to load local files. Can be embarassing for testing

Comment: @TCHdvlp OP mentions PHP as well, so app is served from a webserver and not from a local filesystem environment.